# Run bash script with sudo but create files with user as owner

Tags: bash, macos, sudo

I have a bash script, create-file.sh, that creates a file named a:

```
   $ cat create-file.sh
   # /bin/bash
   touch a
```

When I run the script it creates a file 'a' with my user as owner.

```
 $ ./create-file.sh
 $ ls -l
 -rw-r--r--  1 shai  wheel  0 Aug 16 17:19 a
```

However when I run the script under sudo the file is created with root as user:

```
 $ sudo ./create-file.sh
 $ ls -l
 -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Aug 16 17:19 a
```

Is there a way to tell a script that runs under sudo to create the file with my user as owner?

- you would be correct to say that a script that touches a single file does not need to run under sudo. This example is of course  a reduction of the original problem, my script has much more and does need to run under sudo, but I still want the files to be created with my user as owner.

Comment: The details matter -- the ideal approach might involve something like a non-elevated script running a sudo'd script as a coprocess, for instance. A question focused on a specific solution doesn't allow for a nuanced, tailored answer.

Comment: BTW, `# /bin/bash` is not `#!/bin/bash`; the `!` is mandatory to be a valid shebang.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: of course, `#!/bin/bash`, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` exports the original username as `SUDO_USER`; you can `chown` to that.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch a
[[ $SUDO_USER ]] && chown "$SUDO_USER" a
```

Similarly, if your sudo configuration allows (as is default) root to drop privileges to any other user without an explicit password prompt, you can take advantage of that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# drop privileges back to non-root user if we got here with sudo
depriv() {
  if [[ $SUDO_USER ]]; then
    sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" -- "$@"
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}

depriv touch a
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the correct approach. However this will not scale well if my script creates many files and some of them by calling other scripts or shell commands. I would have to know in advance each file being created.

Comment: If you want to have the default owner for created files to be anything other than the euid -- sorry, that's simply not UNIX semantics. That's why I suggested a coprocess approach, to keep the original euid for everything except the specific portions of the script you need to elevate..

Comment: Alternately, if you use `depriv` to wrap your "other scripts or shell commands" (thus dropping permissions back to the original euid), well, there you are; that's why I provided it.

Comment: ...which is to say, `depriv something` will run `something` as the original user, not root.